# Reading the identity in the Branch Web SDK

Tags: javascript, branch.io

What is the way to read what identity Branch is currently set to?

[`data`](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Web-SDK/blob/master/WEB_GUIDE.md#datacallback)'s result seems to stay the same both before and after `setIdentity` is called, I believe because it just shows you what [`init`](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Web-SDK/blob/master/WEB_GUIDE.md#initbranch_key-options-callback) had called back with.  So, I'm not sure what method to use to check this.

EDIT: Later it was discovered that `setIdentity` wasn't working because of an issue on Branch's end.  After an email discussion with support we narrowed down the issue and they fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not currently a method in the web SDK to read whether the identity is set. I just added a task to the backlog and we'll update this answer after we have one.

In iOS and Android, we've added methods to tell whether or not you've already identified a user.

Objective C:

```
- (BOOL)isUserIdentified;
```

Java:

```
isUserIdentified();
```